# Wrap formula with large brackets

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to display a mathematical formula on my HTML page and want to achieve this without using external libraries or JavaScript frameworks. Is there a way to do this solely using Unicode characters (HTML and CSS)? Specifically, I'm interested in how to create fractions and surround them with big brackets like so:

[image: Example]

https://jsfiddle.net/t12eoqhm/#&togetherjs=v0jEad2fUd

```css
.fraction {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0px;
font-size: 100px;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 100;
}

.numerator, .denominator {
padding: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
}

.line {
border-top: 2px solid black;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=fraction>
<div class=numerator>100 - g</div>
<div class=line></div>
<div class=denominator>100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML) count as external dependency?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. It really needs to be plain HTML and CSS.

Comment: Then... Well, obviously you _can_ (you can display random Unicode characters, make them any size and put them anywhere in the screen). It's a bit unclear what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's very clear what the OP wants to do: _"Specifically, I'm interested in how to create fractions and surround them with big brackets"_. They've even provided a screen shot of what they want to achieve, and sample code. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @skomisa Essentially, that it has little to do with the title. I think I'll just fix the title.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough:

```
<div class=wrapper>
   <div class=numerator>q + b *</div>
   <div class=bracket>(</div>
   <div class=fraction>
      <div class=numerator>100 - g</div>
      <div class=line></div>
      <div class=denominator>100</div>
   </div>
   <div class=bracket>)</div>
</div>
```

Additional css:

```
.bracket {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 90px;
   font-family: math;
}
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```